# Sefer Olat Tamid, 13 fulfillments of bracha

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing

Found this online [here](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/1-What-is-a-Bracha.html):

> *Sefer Olat Tamid* lists 13 verses that one fulfills each time one says
>   a bracha properly. Included among them:
>
> - the mitzvah to remember God (Deut. 8:18)
> - recalling the kindness that God performs for us (Deut. 8:2)
> - being careful not to mention God's name in vain (Exodus 20:7)
> - trying to relate to God in all of our ways (Proverbs 3:6)

Could someone tell me what the other verses are teaching? or tell where in the sefer olat tamid i can find the full list?

Comment: What does it mean to fulfill a verse?

Comment: What is this book and where can we find it?

Comment: @mevakesh http://www.hebrewbooks.org/14187 - This may be the one. There are some others though listed in http://www.hebrewbooks.org